# AGC (Automatic Gain Controller) for DTMF (Dual Tone Multiple Frequency)

Tags: audio, automatic-gain-control

I would like to know if there exist any IC or circuit that can provide AGC ('Automatic Gain Control') functionality for DTMF (Dual Tone Multiple Frequency) input signal.

We need AGC specifically for DTMF tones, because DTMF tone has *Unique* envelope which makes harder for AGC to retain envelop at the output.

If required, we can provide any attenuation or gain to DTMF signal to match ICs characteristics. And *we do not need* any DTMF decoding functionality. We have very specific requirements for DTMF decoding and we already have a solution for that. (We just need an AGC.)

If someone thinks that we can use normal AGC for DTMF decoding, please provide a rough architecture with specifying important ICs.

Thanks.

Comment: Um, I literally can't find *anything* unique about the envelope of DTMF signals; just two tones. In fact, their amplitude shouldn't matter at all for any reasonable decoder! If you need an AGC, the simplest thinkable AGC would do, as these are just the sum of two constant-amplitude oscillations. Can you explain what you're trying to **solve** in the bigger picture?

Comment: I'm asking because questions for product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, and will be closed. However, your question seems to be a technological one, and if you describe what problem you're solving with the AGC, and what you've tried so far, this would be a very valid question that's not just "tell me what to buy so that I don't have to think myself", but a "Help me solve this interesting problems, the solution of which might be helpful to others, too".

Comment: I also ask because your say "We have very specific requirements" but then... forget to mention any of these requirements! How should we help you build something that fulfills requirements if we don't know them?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. DTMF tones for digits 1 and 4. Extracted from image on [Tech-FAQ](http://www.tech-faq.com/wp-content/uploads/frequencies-of-the-telephone-tones.png) which shows all twelve standard tones. (The standard has 16 available.) The image is taken from the article [Frequencies of the telephone tones](http://www.tech-faq.com/frequencies-of-the-telephone-tones.html) where it appears as a thumbnail.*

DTMF tones are constant amplitude. The apparent "envelope" is simply the result of the addition of two sines.

If you *do* try to implement an AGC circuit then you need to set the AGC time constant long enough that the gain won't "pump" between the peaks and troughs of the sum waveform.